# wpf datagrid is not editable

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a problem with `WpfDataGrid`.
I created a control and this control open a window

```
var wb = new DataEntry(b, Connectionstring);
wb.Show();
```

The window `DataEntry` contains `TextBox` and a `DataGrid` which are showing as non-editable.

I read a post that suggests to insert:

`ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(wb);` before `wb.Show();`

I tried that and now `TextBox` working well but `DataGrid` is still not editable.

Thank you for support.

I add the code that I Use

```
DataEntry class 

private ObservableCollection<RigaBarcode> _righeBarcode = new ObservableCollection<RigaBarcode>();


//so I create the customer object

  private class RigaBarcode : INotifyPropertyChanged 
        {
            public RigaBarcode(string barcode, string coordinate)
            {
                Barcode = barcode;
                Coordinate = coordinate;

            }

            private string _barcode;
            private string _coordinate;
```

....
whit setter and getter

```
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
            {
                PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
                if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
```

I add and element to this collection

```
_righeBarcode.Add(new RigaBarcode("1", "2");
```

in xaml I insert

```
DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding .}" Name="Fustelle" Margin="10,23,10,10" Grid.Row="8" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsReadOnly="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            DataGrid.Columns>
                    DataGridTextColumn  Header="BarCode" Width="90" Binding="{Binding Barcode}"/>
                    DataGridTextColumn  Header="Posizione" Width="90" Binding="{Binding Coordinate}"/>
                /DataGrid.Columns>
            /DataGrid>
```

SO I expect that when the windows is initialized the datagrid has 1 row editable but the datagrid doesn't present this row and I can't add other row

Comment: What is your question? Do you want to make the `DataGrid` editable? What have you tried? Does the documentation say that is supports editing?

Comment: at the beginning I write this code  
wb = new DataEntry(b, Connectionstring); 
ElementHost.EnableModelessKeyboardInterop(wb);
wb.Show(); 
in a window form and it works. but it is only a test.
For the release version I need to insert it in a wpf window and when I do it the datagrid become not editable

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

> By default, you can edit items directly in the DataGrid. To guarantee that edits can be committed and canceled correctly, the objects in the DataGrid must implement the IEditableObject interface. Alternatively, you can set the IsReadOnly property to true to disable editing in the DataGrid.

You didn't state which verison of the framework you're using and whether your data objects implement the [IEditableObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ieditableobject.aspx) interface.
As far as I'm aware, this is only supported in .Net 4.0 and up.

Comment: I use .NET 4.0 I try to implement IEditableObject but I have no result

Comment: Did you read the MSDN article I linked to? Did you try subscribing to the different events such as *BeginEditCommand* ? Does pressing F2 have any effect?

Comment: In your code I don't see an implementation of IEditableObject

Comment: I insert IEditableObject but the problem is that I also can't view the row that I have load from database